# Ndb debugger for node.js won't start

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-22.04, ndb

Im trying to start the ndb debugger from VS code, but every time i run the "ndb server.js" command, a window opens and closes immediately and i get this error:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {   errno: -104,   code:
'ECONNRESET',   syscall: 'read' }
```

My OS is ubuntu 22.04.
I've tried running these two commands from https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb/issues/312, but no luck.

```
npm install -g --prefix=$HOME/.npm ndb 
export PATH="$HOME/.npm/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that this package hasn't been kept up since 2019. I wonder if doesn't work the way it used to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).